# Is Returning by Reference Useless?

Tags: c++

Coming from a C# background, I was more or less puzzled by the seemly weird behavior of returning method handling in C++. My concern now is for a method in C++, returning by reference is not a very useful technique, this is because-- unlike C#--any variable declared inside a method body will go out of scope once the the control exit the method.

So, in C++, [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/) cannot even compile ( but an equivalent version in C# *can*):

```
int& DoubleValue(int nX)
{
    int nValue = nX * 2;
    return nValue; // return a reference to nValue here
} // nValue goes out of scope here
```

The only time where returning by reference is useful is when you are returning a reference to an existing data member in a class, or you are returning a reference to an element inside a parameter of the method. But in both cases there is really no need to return anything; as the  returned reference is already freely available to the caller of the method.

So, my conclusion is, there is no need to use return by reference at all. Am I right?

Comment: It can and does compile. That's one of things that is so very wrong with c++. To be fair, you'll get a warning.

Comment: Your conclusion is that return-by-reference is not *necessary*. Your title asks whether it's *useless*. Please note that those are not opposites. It's possible for things to be neither.

Comment: Can you please post the equivalent C# code that returns a local variable by reference? (I'm not saying it's not possible, I'm genuinely asking out of curiosity.)

Comment: @FredOverflow, in C# everything is returned by reference if the object is a `class`, instead of a `struct` ( here's another great difference between C# and C++), so if you instantiate a class object inside your method and return it, then you are already returned by reference.

Comment: You are either talking about returning a class object by reference or returning a reference to a class object by value. I mean something else entirely. I want to see C# code that returns **a variable** by reference, so that the client can say `foo(42) = x;` Is something like that possible in C# with the `ref` keyword or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The only time where returning by reference is useful is when you are returning a reference to an existing data member in a class, or you are returning a reference to an element inside a parameter of the method.

Loosely speaking, true.  The variable might not be "owned" by the class (as in tied to its lifetime): it could have been specified to the class by some earlier function call, or a global/singleton known to the class but not part of it, or even a newly allocated area in shared memory or the heap (though returning a reference rather than a pointer suggests the ownership isn't being given to the caller), but ultimately the class must have some access to that data.

> But in both cases there is really no need to return anything; as the returned reference is already freely available to the caller of the method.

No, because objects can have private and protected members, and grant friendship to other classes or functions, so it's entirely possible that a called function can access (and hence return a reference to) some data that the caller has no direct access to.

Further, many functions find a specific variable to do some work on, then return a reference to it.  If the caller needed to make a separate call to find that variable again, it could be inefficient (as well as verbose in the calling code).

> So, my conclusion is, there is no need to use return by reference at all. Am I right?

Nope... due to the flawed premise above.

Another non-necessary but convenient use of return by reference is illustated by typical streaming functions:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    return os << x.str();
}
```

Above, the reference to means say...

```
std::cout << x << y;
```

...is evaluated as...

```
(std::cout << x) << y;
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, x), y)
```

Which all chains together nicely.  Similarly:

```
while (std::cin >> x >> y)
    ...
```

...works not only due to the chaining for successive inputs to x and y, but also because std::cin is still available for evaluation in a boolean context, which ends up invoking another member function effectively asking whether the streaming operations worked.

Answer (score 11):

Operations like `std::vector<>::operator[]` return references to elements obtained by dereferencing a pointer (and adding offsets to it).  The pointer in that case is a `private` member internal to the `vector`, and so not something the user could have obtained themselves without breaking the abstraction of the class.

Comment: And as an example for the OP's benefit: `vector<int> xs(10); xs[5] = 42;` That assignment can't possibly take place without a reference returned by the overloaded operator.

Comment: @chrisaycock: `struct vec { struct proxy { proxy(int* e) : e(e) {} void operator=(int i) { *e = i } int *e; }; proxy operator[](unsigned i) { return proxy(data + i); } int* data; };` and then `vec v; v[5] = 42`; no references needed. (Yes, I get your point, but it's *possible* without references; references can almost always be replaced by pointers...almost.)

Comment: @Logan: Of course it doesn't, but that's outside of its intended domain.

Comment: @Logan Agreed. Since `vector<T>::operator[]` returns a `T&`, the user can do whatever a `T` can do without redefining a ton of operations.

Comment: Most damning, you *can* pass `xs[5]` to `void foo(int&)` but you can't pass a `proxy<int>` to foo.

Answer (score 5):

It is correct that this doesn't work for returning a reference to something allocated on the stack. That simply can't work.

However returning by reference can still be extremely useful - for example, a collection's indexing operator can return a value by reference, thus enabling you to assign to that element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to mention that besides returning references to private/protected data members and the chaining of operators, there are techniques in template meta-programming that make use of functions that return-by-reference to temporary variables. This can have a performance gain, but obviously, it needs to be done with care. The [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) library is one example of expression templates techniques that use references to temporaries to avoid creating temporaries. I'm sorry I cannot really give a simple example of it... I'm not sure I understand it myself, but I just wanted to point out that even the most illogical things in C++ are still allowed, and if they are allowed, someone will find a way to use it wisely. And that includes returning a reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int & DV(int & nX)
{     
     return nX *= 2;     
}
// . . .
int i = 2;
int & j = DV(DV(i));
```

Comment: what is the relevant of this to my question?

Comment: @Graviton: it's syntactic convenience to have the object modified through the reference also in the function return.

Comment: ah I got your point; the modification of a value via chaining of method is indeed nice.

Answer (score 0):

I hope other experts will come up with more detailed explanation. I just trying to say a few cases when C/C++ programmers use reference types.

The C++ references type is just a syntactic enhancement over the old pointer type of C. In C/C++ all the parameters and return values are value type. That is, values are copied to/from caller/callee. Apparently this is not the desired operation always. So when C/C++ programmers want to prevent unnecessary copying they use pointers or references.

- To pass large size value
- To allow caller/callee modify the value

Well.. any other?

Answer (score 0):

The usual purpose of return by reference, is so that chained assignments can be made, like this:

```
MyVar1 = MyVar2 = Myvar3 = MyVar4;
```

Comment: That doesn't require return by reference.

Comment: @GMan: for classes, the above requires an `operator=` that returns something indicative of value of *this.  References are certainly the most direct and efficient approach.  Proxy objects and by-value return may also work, but aren't typically credible as valid design alternatives.

Comment: @Tony: I agree. That doesn't make the answer correct. You simply don't need references as a return type. I'm not saying avoiding references is good practice, I'm not saying we should do so or find a work around, I'm just saying it's false to say they are *required* in this context.